# How to fix '-[__NSArrayM totalLength]: unrecognized

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm setting up

```
appDele.mMediaManager=[[BluzManager alloc] initWithConnector:appDele.mBluzConnector];
```

and Third-party library methods are also implemented. When I init object then the problem goes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM totalLength]: unrecognized

Is the NSArray about _m_arrBT goes wrong?

```
 -(void)connectedPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{

    if (m_dictConnect != nil) {

        BOOL found = NO;
        for (int i = 0; i < _m_arrBT.count; i++) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [_m_arrBT objectAtIndex:i];
            CBPeripheral *device = [dict objectForKey:@"peripheral"];
            CBPeripheral *connected = [m_dictConnect objectForKey:@"peripheral"];
            //     if (device.UUID == connected.UUID) {
            if ([self isPeripheral:device equalPeripheral:connected]) {
                found = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            [_m_arrBT addObject:m_dictConnect];
        }
        _m_arrBT = [self sortDeviceArray:_m_arrBT];
    } else {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in _m_arrBT) {
            CBPeripheral *device = [dict objectForKey:@"peripheral"];
            //    if (device.UUID == peripheral.UUID) {
            if ([self isPeripheral:device equalPeripheral:peripheral]) {
                NSLog(@"devicename=%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
            }
        }
    }

    appDele.mMediaManager=[[BluzManager alloc] initWithConnector:appDele.mBluzConnector];
    appDele.globalManager=[appDele.mMediaManager getGlobalManager:self];
    mUserDiconnected = NO;
    m_bConnect=YES;

    _m_arrBT = [self sortDeviceArray:_m_arrBT];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    if (!mManagerReady || !mHotplugCardArrived || !mHotplugUhostArrived || !mHotplugUSBArrived) {

       // [self managerReady];
    }


}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posed calls `totalLength`, and you haven't indicated which line generates the crash. That should be clear from the backtrace. Something in one of the methods you're called passes `-totalLength` to an `NSArray` (which is incorrect). I expect it's in `BluzManager`, whatever that is.

Comment: As a wild guess, `totalLength` might be a category in the third party library. Check if `-ObjC` is set as a linker flag. If it's not set, then try adding `-ObjC` in other linker flags.

Comment: In the future, please update your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015553/how-to-fix-nsarraym-totallength-unrecognized-selector-sent-to) instead of posting a whole new question.

Comment: -Objc really helped me,Tks @Jeffery Thomas